# Using Cartthrob with Stripe - form being submitted even with errors

Tags: cartthrob, stripe

I'm using the Stripe payment gateway with Cartthrob which appeared to be working properly. On further inspection it appears that the form is being submitted to Stripe when the submit button is clicked even if there are errors.

Trying to disable the form submission isn't working either. This results in failed attempts in the Stripe logs.

Has anyone got Stripe working properly with Cartthrob? How are you preventing this?

Comment: I think I have worked this out. For the moment I have removed my custom form validation and I'm just letting Stripe do it's own validation. This is why the request is being sent each time. I would like to add some additional validation for some fields that Stripe doesn't check.

Answer (score 0):

Im using the straight forward validation currently and having no problems, although I'm not receiving the emails from Stripe at present or the system which is a little worrying..

which other validation are you using?